# Academic postdoc: Interview process time insights

Tags: interview, science, biology

I had an informal meeting via Skype for a postdoc position that I am highly interested in, speaking of which, I was invited for a formal interview soon after. I was asked to give a talk to the lab (online) about my PhD work. The talk went well and there were questions that I answered in the best possible way I could. I was then asked to talk to the lab members in the absence of the PI. After that, I asked about the next step in the process and was told that they would reach via email.

How long should I wait before I feel, my chances to get the position, have gone? Should I wait for two to three weeks? What is the normal time for the process to complete? Any insight would quiet my fears.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

The time can be highly variable as there may be several people who need to give approvals and they may not all be available in a given time frame. There may be administrative issues that they need to resolve, etc.

I suggest that you wait as long as it takes, but ask for an update after two or three weeks. But, if you have other options, don't give them up and continue any necessary process in case it doesn't happen after all.

Keep a positive, but slightly skeptical attitude until you sign formally.

Comment: Another source of variability is that there may be a large delay if someone else is offered the job, whether or not they accept it.  During the period that the first offer is being considered, other candidates will typically be left in the dark about what's happening.  If that other candidate ultimately turns down the job, you may get a later offer.